# Proper way to mount a toolpost to a lathe

Tags: machining, machine-design

I recently bought [a lathe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09B73X57M) of the A site that was quite clearly from China. It claims to be 8" x 23". It came with a turret style tool-post which, frankly, I don't want to deal with shims so I bought a SHARS [OXA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087QMBF32) and [AXA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087QMBF32) quick-change tool-post (free returns), and I'm trying to decide which to install. I think I'm going to keep the larger one (AXA) and I was drawing up a way to mount the post to the lathe compound when I realized that there is a "nubbin" on the compound [image: compound_nubbin] where the turret style post's bolt attached to the cross slide.

I am trying to figure out what the best plan is do I:

1. Grind off the nubbin, and increase the hole size on the cross slide from M8 to M12 so I can mount the AXA tool post directly?
2. Grind off the nubbin, and mount the toolpost mount plate to the cross slide and then the AXA tool post to that?
3. Grind off the nubbin, give up on the AXA and go with the OXA which use M8, and mount the tool post directly to the currently existing hole?
4. Leave the nubbin and shim  around it so that the OXA tool post mounts above the existing hole?

My concern is primarily why does the "nubbin" exist is it for strength? or just to give the turret style post something to rotate around? I am heartened that the mount plate that came with the AXA tool post is the exact thickness of the cross slide above the dovetail, with the nubbin removed.

[image]

This might be largely "opinion" based, but I'm hoping I can get some real engineers feedback on the various methods and their effects on the lathe system.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d84weTMG7ek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I'm much closer to being a "real machinist" than a "real (mechanical) engineer".]

I'm going to guess that the stock toolpost is one of the "4 way turret" ones, vaguely like this:

[image]

Unlike this one, however, in your case the "nubbin" fits into a counterbored hole in the bottom of the toolpost.

I think it's primarily to provide a bearing surface, so as you rotate the toolpost, it maintains its position. For example, if you rotate it a full turn, and tighten it back in place, your tool should still be pretty close to the same position relative to the work piece (within a thousandth or so).

As to what to do...I'd prefer to counterbore the bottom of the toolpost over grinding off the nubbin. Leaving the nubbin intact means it can continue to accomplish what it was put there to accomplish in the first place, and most QC toolposts won't be adversely affected by counterboring the bottom of the mounting hole. To maximize its benefit, you want your counterbore to be a nice, tight fit over the "nubbin".

#### Image Source

https://www.penntoolco.com/precise-revolving-tool-post-turret-with-swing-of-range-6-to-12-rtp-001/